# Seeking & reading arbitrary file data in Metro

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, file-access

I'm having an inordinate amount of trouble doing something that really should be very simple: Getting arbitrary data from a file in a C# Win8 Metro-style app.

Given a StorageFile object that references an existing file, I need to be able to seek to arbitrary positions and then read arbitrary values (integers of various sizes, strings, bytes, arrays of bytes, whatever). Nothing I've tried has worked.

For example, I obtained an `IRandomAccessStream` using `StorageFile.OpenAsync`, constructed a `DataReader` with it, and used `DataReader.ReadByte` to read the first byte of the file. But `ReadByte` throws an exception ("The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range").

It probably doesn't help that I'm relatively new to both C# and .NET.

Can someone outline how to do this?

---

I was asked for a code example. Here is what I described above, one of many different attempts. These may not even be the right types. `f` is a valid `StorageFile` that refers to an existing file, picked by the user (so there are no permission issues).

```
public async void Read(StorageFile f)
{
  IRandomAccessStream s = await f.OpenAsynch(FileAccessMode.Read);
  DataReader r = new DataReader(s);
  Byte b = r.ReadByte();
}
```

The `ReadByte` call is the one that throws the exception.

Comment: Can you provide a code example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I'm using to read an entire file as string:

```
        using (var fs = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            using (var inStream = fs.GetInputStreamAt(0))
            {
                using (var reader = new DataReader(inStream))
                {
                    await reader.LoadAsync((uint)fs.Size);
                    string data = reader.ReadString((uint)fs.Size);
                    reader.DetachStream();
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }
```

One obvious option to seek to some position would be to pass another value into GetInputStreamAt(). To read bytes - you would just call reader.ReadBytes(). If something does not work in this scenario - it is likely caused by bugs/incomplete implementation in WinRT. I would speculate that reading files should become much simpler than using 4 different proxy classes, so this could change.

Comment: Thanks, the `LoadAsync()` call was the bit I was missing. Wish the docs were a little more helpful.